# How to copy/move only new records from Table in dev environment to same table in Test environment

Tags: sql-server, database, copy

I have added some new records in table `Table_1` in dev database server. I have exactly same table `Table_1` in test database server. I only want to copy the records from table `Table_1` in dev database server to the same table `Table_1` in test database server which are not present in `Table_1` on test database server. What is the best way?

Comment: Do a SELECT INTO SERVER with a subquery filtering DEV with NOT IN

Comment: if any example, that will be good?

Comment: Do you have a linked server setup between the two?  If so, then you can query them directly (as though they were two tables in the same db).  If not, then you need to create a linked server or use a tool like Import/Export Wizard, define your source and destination and then define the query.  Is your question a t-sql one (ie. "how to find rows that exist in one table that aren't in another"?) or is it "how to move data across servers", or both?

Comment: my question is t-sql one (ie. "how to find rows that exist in one table that aren't in another"?)

Answer (score 1):

```
Insert into servername.testdb.dbo.Table_1 (ID, column1, column2, etc)
Select ID, column1, column2, etc
From Devdb.dbo.Table_1
Where ID Not IN (Select ID From servername.testdb.dbo.Table_1)
```

If the ID is an Identity column, you will have to Set Identity_Insert before and after your inserts and also you'd have to run the insert from the Test server and pull the data from Dev.

Comment: This is correct but only if the servers are linked.

Comment: @WEI_DBA, where i run this query? on test server or dev server?

Comment: The statement above is run from the DEV Server. And yes, if you have linked servers. If not, the statement will error out.